# retrieve data of a row and get header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve data in a row with the name and the header.
   I really appreciate your help

```
NAME            AUG 1, 2019          AUG 2, 2019          AUG 3, 2019
Zoldyk,Hunter        5                                         7
Luffy,One            1                    2                    3
```

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngTemp As Range, rngTarget As Range
Dim intMultiple As Integer, i As Integer, intRow As Integer
Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Set objSheet = Sheets(1)
Dim intLastCellIndexInRow As Integer
intLastCellIndexInRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
Dim strRowValue As String
Dim j As Integer

Set rngCopy = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'Set range including names
Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'Set target range to next available row in Sheet2

`For intRow = rngCopy.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set rngTemp = rngCopy.Cells(intRow)
    intMultiple = rngTemp.Offset(0, 1) 'Find how many times to copy the name
        For i = 1 To intMultiple
            For j = 3 To intLastCellIndexInRow
            rngTarget.Value = rngTemp.Value 'Copy name
            rngTarget.Next.Value = objSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, j) 'Copy ID
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0) 'Move target range to next row

        Next
        Next
Next
End Sub
```

- Zoldyk,hunter|5|aug 1,2019
- Zoldyk,hunter| |aug 2,2019
- Zoldyk,hunter|7|aug 3,2019
- Luffy,One    |1|aug 1,2019
- Luffy,One    |2|aug 2,2019
- Luffy,One    |3|aug 3,2019

Comment: Is the code not working ?

Comment: It only generates list of names

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? There are two techniques that spring to mind that don't involve VBA at all.

Comment: It can be vba for 1 click only, but if you have an idea I love to hear that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notes:**

- Didn't understand your loop,so I have changed it completely
- Try and remove the extra declarations that are left in the code.
- You can manipulate it to print on other sheet.
- You can also use Pivot for this.

**Use the Below code :**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngTemp As Range, rngTarget As Range
Dim intMultiple As Integer, i As Integer, intRow As Integer
Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Set objSheet = Sheets(1)

Dim strRowValue As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim cl As Integer

Set rngCopy = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'Set range including names
Set rngTarget = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'Set target range to next available row in Sheet2\


cl = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
i = rngTarget.row

For Each cel In rngCopy.Cells

    For j = 2 To cl

        With Sheet1
        .Range("A" & i).Value = cel.Value
        .Range("B" & i).Value = .Cells(cel.row, j).Value
        .Range("C" & i).Value = .Cells(1, j).Value
        i = i + 1
        End With

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i want to post the output 1st column name 2nd column the data the 3rd column is the date

Comment: wait i will try your demo

Comment: @Chaoski .. See the demo. It provides output just like you mentioned in question.

Comment: It works, can you help me again to make the output 1ST COLUMN NAME, 2ND COLUMN DATA, 3RD COLUMN DATE, not in 1 cell thank you

Comment: @Chaoski .. Updated the Answer. Accept & Upvote the answer